# How do I bandpass a signal in Mathematica 8

Tags: signal-processing

I would like to use the bandpassing function that is available in newer versions of Mathematica but not Mathematica 8:

```
BANDPASSALPHA[x_] := 
 BandpassFilter[x, {8 Pi, 13 Pi}, SampleRate -> 500]
```

Is there a pice of custom code that would allow me to do this?

Comment: A crude filtering could be done with `Fourier`, a window and `InverseFourier`. If you want to use specific FIR/IIR filters with certain guarantees of performance in the pass/stop bands, then you're going to have to write a lot of the code yourself. If you have access to MATLAB (and the DSP toolbox), then I suggest using the functions from it in _Mathematica_ 8.

Comment: @rm-rf If you have time would you outline the steps that would need to be implemented for the accurate *Mathematica* 8 solution?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, sorry. It's a lot of time commitment and detail that's well beyond the scope of this site. OP still hasn't replied to my question re: MATLAB. If that's the case, then the second example [here](http://matlink.org/examples/) would be the best way to proceed.

Comment: @rm-rf It sounds like you are already familiar with the process and I meant only a very brief outline.  Nevertheless I completely understand you not wanting to take time for it, whatever the amount.

Answer (score 4):

There [is a paper by Slaney from 1989](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~malcolm/apple/tr34/FilterDesign.pdf) with quite detailed code for filter design.